# SVGTextElement.getComputedTextLength not supported by jsdom

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs, jsdom, recharts

In a `Create React App` project I have a component that outputs a svg element (Label for a [recharts](https://recharts.org/en-US/api/ReferenceLine) `ReferenceLine` component. It takes a rendered SVGTextElement as a MutableRef and  calculates the computedWidth of the element. It works fine except when I run my jest/jsdom tests where I get this error

> TypeError: textRef.current.getComputedTextLength is not a function

I tried different ways to mock the function:

In `setupTests`:

```
const globalAny: any = global
globalAny.window.SVGTextElement.prototype.getComputedTextLength = jest.fn()
```

In a `beforeEach`:

```
beforeEach(() => {
  window.SVGTextElement.prototype.getComputedTextLength = () => 100
})
```

Nothing works. I found [this old thread](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2697) about the problem but it seems to have been closed and forgotten.

How do I get past this error?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar code, I am using `getBBox` on a `SVGTextElement` ref. I found out that during the test the `SVGTextElement` ref is a `SVGElement` type. That is probably a bug inside JsDomEnv. I was able to run the test using a workaround. I did not find any better solution yet:

```
(global.SVGElement.prototype as any).getBBox = function () {
      return {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
        width: 30,
        height: 15,
        bottom: 0,
        left: 0,
        right: 0,
        top: 0,
        toJSON: () => '',
      };
    };
```

It would most likely work for your case also.